# Having trouble installing lxml for Python3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a while now i have been trying to figure out how to install lxml but have had no such luck. As a last ditch of hope. I've come here for some solutions or clarification. So far I've already tried nearly all the ways told before in other answer threads but have had no luck.

Firstly I've tried the following:

```
 pip install lxml 

 pip3 install lxml

python -m pip install lxml
```

Which threw an error...

```
ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit1owazwq3.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
```

I then went on and tried to install wheel...

```
python -m pip install wheel 

C:\Users\Me>python -m pip install wheel
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wheel in c:\python35\lib\site-packages
```

Which seems to have worked.

However when i tried to install lxml again...

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    Command "c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-klrlh4_w\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-k3saekal-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-klrlh4_w\lxml\
```

i then tried downloading the .whl files..

```
python -m pip install lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

^Downloaded nearly all of these .whl files 

 
only to come to the same conclusion each and every

```
lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Sadly none of these have been able to install lxml...

Is lxml able to run on python3.5.1?

Any help at all will be helpful :)

Comment: Which python version are you using? The wheel file is for 64-bit python. If your Python is 32-bit then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry forgot to clarify that, ok it seems that python is using 32-bit...

Comment: Then you probably need lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Comment: Ahhhh wow, silly me.Thank you so much, you are a saint. That was literally one of the only ones i hadn't tried.

Answer (score 1):

Check what version you need to download with...

```
import sys

is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32

print(is_64bits )
```

Then download the right version of lxml.. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

All credit goes to @Manjabes - https://stackoverflow.com/users/396571/manjabes

Thanks for the help <3